# Javascript regex match for string "game_1"

Tags: javascript, regex

I just can't get this thing to work in javascript. So, I have a text "game_1" without the quotes and now i want to get that number out of it and I tried this:

```
var idText = "game_1";
re = /game_(.*?)/;
found = idText.match(re);

var ajdi = found[1];
alert( ajdi );
```

But it doesn't work - please point out where am I going wrong.

Comment: Is this always the whole text, `"game_X"` ? I mean, does the string only consist of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only matching a number, you may want to try

```
/game_([0-9]+)/
```

as your regular expression. That will match *at least one* number, which seems to be what you need. You entered a regexp that allows for 0 characters (`*`) and let it select the shortest possible result (`?`), which may be a problem (and match you 0 characters), depending on the regex engine.

Comment: I tried your test here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html but it's not working :(

Comment: `[0-9]+` is more precise, which is always better.

Comment: Really? It works perfectly for me both on that page and on Regexp Buddy. Did you remove the // before trying it on the page?

Comment: @Nikola: Please provide an example where this expression does not work. It should!

Comment: @all: I entered /game_([0-9]+)/ as an Regexp and game_1 in the Subject string and I get no match

Comment: @Nikola: Then you are doing something wrong, because it clearly works: http://jsfiddle.net/YQ87J/

Comment: @Felix: I ment, it doesn't work on this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html . I tried it out in my code and it works there though...

Comment: The site you're testing on requires you to remove the slashes. I added the slashes because you use them in javascript. Try testing with `game_([0-9]+)`.

Comment: @Nikola: The slashes are **not** part of the regular expression, hence you should not add them. The slashes are used to create a regex literal in JavaScript, but, as said, they are not part of the expression.

Answer (score 4):

If this is the complete text, then there is no need for regular expressions:

```
var id = +str.split('_')[1];
```

or

```
var id = +str.replace('game_', '');
```

*(unary `+` is to convert the string to a number)*

---

If you insist on regular expression, you have to anchor the expression:

```
/^game_(.*?)$/
```

or make the `*` *greedy* by omitting the `?`:

```
/game_(.*)/
```

Better is to make the expression more restrictive as [@Naltharial suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608223/javascript-regex-match-for-string-game-1/6608274#6608274).

Comment: nice, good one! But since I asked for a regex, I'll mark katspaugh as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`*` means zero or more occurrences. It seems that combining it with a greediness controller `?` results in zero match.

You could replace `*` with `+` (which means *one* or more occurrences), but as @Felix Kling notes, it would only match *one* digit.

Better to ditch the `?` completely.

http://jsfiddle.net/G8Qt7/2/

Comment: Or add anchors: `re = /^game_(.*?)$/;`

Comment: @Felix Kling, `?` to blame, that Ebenezer Scrooge. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple string manipulation:

```
var idText = "game_1",
    adji = parseInt(idText.substring(5), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `"game_1".replace(/^(game_)/, '')`
this will return the number

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this re `/\d+/` to get any number inside your string